# On Site Page Quick Launch Dissapears - how to prevent it

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, quick-launch

**What I have**
I use SharePoint 365 online (publishing site)
I have a Site Page with quick launch enabled on the site.
When the page loads the links are visible for a second an then they are covered by the rest of the page.

**What I want to do**
I want to have quick launch or at least a left margin in the modern site page.

Comment: Have you changed the Master Page? Modern or Classic experience? Custom CSS or scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a couple things depending on your situation.

Have a look at the site Navigation Settings. Check Navigation and make sure that under Current Navigation you have anything either Checked (Pages/Subsites) or add manually links and compare the results.

It may also be the Master Page you are using (if it is custom). Try changing the Master page back to the seattle.master and compare the results.